# hyperlinks to each row in flextable

Tags: r, flextable, formattable

I have a data frame

```
df = data.frame("A" = c("a","b","c","d"), "B" = c(1,2,3,4), "link" = c("www.a.com", "www.b.com", "www.c.com", "www.d.com"))
```

> A B      link
>
> a 1 www.a.com
>
> b 2 www.b.com
>
> c 3 www.c.com
>
> d 4 www.d.com

I make the format table

```
dt.ft <- regulartable(data = dt[, list(A, B, link)])
```

I want to have the values in column "A" hyperlinked with corresponding values in "link" column.

I tried

```
compose(x = dt.ft, j = "A", value = as_paragraph( hyperlink_text(x = A, url = link)))
```

and I got following error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "url", value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L,  : 
>     replacement has 16 rows, data has 4

The above R statement works if there is only 1 row in the table, but fails to work on multiple rows. Can you please help me.
Also, is there any way to hide/remove the column "link", after linking.

Comment: thanks, that's a bug. I just fixed it. Would you mind to test the github version?

Comment: Thanks. that worked. Also, any suggestion how to hide/remove the column "link". I had it in the table at first place so I can provide the hyperlink information.

Comment: Also, i dont know how it works, but are you going to release the fixed version or only way is to do it on development version.

Comment: I am preparing a cran release so you are expressing the issue at the most relevant moment :)

Comment: I will reply to all below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there was an issue, the version 0.5.2 should fix it.

```
library(flextable)

df = data.frame("A" = c("a","b","c","d"), "B" = c(1,2,3,4), "link" = c("www.a.com", "www.b.com", "www.c.com", "www.d.com"))
dt.ft <- flextable(data = df, col_keys = c("A", "B"))
dt.ft <- compose(x = dt.ft, j = 1, value = as_paragraph( hyperlink_text(x = A, url = link)))
dt.ft
```

The example show also how to select columns you want to be displayed by using argument `col_keys`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my ignorance. but is it released now? I am not able to get the 0.5.2 version from install.packages("flextable", version = "0.5.2")

Comment: no, there are few steps before you can get the latest version from CRAN. 1 I need to submit 2 the package is beeing inspected by cran team or tools 3 if ok, it goes on CRAN